# Should it be "in" or "to" in "teach history education in / to early childhood"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Can I use either "in" or "to" in the sentence below?
For some reason both sounds awkward to me..

> According to the majority of opinions, playing traditional games, visiting cultural sites, and using fairy tales as appropriate ways to **teach** history education **in/to** early childhood.

Answer (score 2):

"Early Childhood" refers to a specific time period. So you would say "..teach history education **in** early childhood.", as you would be **in** that time period.

An example of using **to** would be "teach history education **to** a young child". As this is talking about a person, "Young Child" rather than a time period, "Early Childhood".